# Check in Sql data " IF " *.text of each button exists

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this form:[image]

Also in my Sql, there is this table

[image]

I want to check in Sql data ‘IF’ *.Text of each button exists and if exist change the color to red.
I’m using this code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = newSystem.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer1.Interval = 3000;//3 seconds
timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlCommand CheckNone = new SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT * from tables where 
tablenumber=101 ) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", con);
con.Open();

var result = (int)CheckNone.ExecuteScalar();
if (result == 0)
{
button4.BackColor = Color. Green;
}
else
button4.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

……… doing the same with the rest of my buttons

But I want to avoid writing the code for all buttons.
I want to check automatically if button.text exist in sql data and if it exists to change the color to red.

I tried this code but it doesn’t work.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
Button btn = c as Button;
{
SqlCommand CheckNone = new SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT * from tables where 
tablenumber= '" + c.Text + "' ) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", con);     
con.Open();

var result = (int)CheckNone.ExecuteScalar();
if (result == 0)
{
c.BackColor = Color. Green;
}
else
c.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Is there any other way for doing this?

OR its better using Tag Property?

Comment: i would suggest using a sql dependency. also don't add/delete records to represent state - use a new column. then select all the tables and dynamically create the controls.

Comment: It would be cleaner, instead of using that "IF" clause, to simply do a "SELECT tablenumber FROM tablenumber WHERE tablenumber=" + c.TEXT and then check the record count you get back (zero, it doesn't exist). As a note, it's not a good idea to call your table "tablenumber" and then a field inside the table "tablenumber" as well. I have some code that does what you want for buttons dynamically. If you want me to submit it as an answer, I'm happy to do so, but as Daniel says above, the way you are handling SQL is not good at the moment.

Comment: Thank you sir. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Its better for me using TAG Property?